# userToken does not have a user_id or is not matching with user.id in making chatApp using node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

in making a chat app i keep getting this error {userToken does not have a user_id or is not matching with user.id}
My code is as following

```
////////FOR AUTH.js IN SERVER////////////////
const signup = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { fullName, username, password, phoneNumber } = req.body;

        const userId = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');

        const serverClient = connect(api_key, api_secret, app_id);

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
        
        const token = serverClient.createUserToken(userId);

        res.status(200).json({ token, fullName, username, userId, hashedPassword, phoneNumber });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

        res.status(500).json({ message: error });
    }
};
//////////////////////////

/////////FOR APP.jsx IN CLIENT////////////////
const authToken = cookies.get("token");
if(authToken) {
  client.connectUser({
      id: cookies.get('userId'),
      name: cookies.get('username'),
      fullName: cookies.get('fullName'),
      image: cookies.get('avatarURL'),
      hashedPassword: cookies.get('hashedPassword'),
      phoneNumber: cookies.get('phoneNumber'),
  }, authToken)
}

const App = () => {
  if(!authToken) return <Auth/>
  
  return (
    <div className='app__wrapper'>
      <Chat client={client} theme='team light'>

        <ChannelListContainer
        
        />
        <ChannelContainer
        
        />
      </Chat>
    </div>
  )
}
/////////////////////////////////////

///////////////FOR AUTH.jsx IN CLIENT WHEN PRESSING SUBMIT BUTTON//////////////
const handleSubmit = async(e) =>{
        e.preventDefault(); //TO PREVENT RELOAD WHICH WILL LOOSE INFORMATION
        const {username ,password,fullName ,phoneNumber,avatarURL} = form;
        const URL  = 'http://localhost:5000/auth';

        //passing data from frontend
        const { data: { token, userId, hashedPassword } } = await axios.post(`${URL}/${isSignup ? 'signup' : 'login'}`, {
            username, password, fullName, phoneNumber, avatarURL,
        });

        cookies.set('token' , token);
        cookies.set('userId' , userId);
        cookies.set('userName' , username);
        cookies.set('fullName' , fullName);
        

        if(isSignup){
            cookies.set('phoneNumber' , phoneNumber);
        cookies.set('avatarURL' , avatarURL);
        cookies.set('hashedPassword' , hashedPassword);
        }
        window.location.reload();
    }`
//////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I expect to add the user in getstream.io ChatExplorer but it did not add any.
these are the cookies value showing

Cookie value where muhammad-abdullah is the app id name in getstream.io

[image]

The error

[image]

Can you please explain the error and how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not using cookie-parser

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser